# Android load different layout according to OS

Tags: android, android-layout, android-2.2-froyo, android-timepicker

My supported OS versions are >= 2.2

Now i want to use some >= 4.0 views in my application, So whats the best way to load different layouts according to different os? say I want to use default time picker in android os < 4.0 and holo theme time picker in android >= 4.0

Is it possible? whats the best way?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) article.

Basically you can define different layouts per API level (and many other qualifiers). In your case, you would have:

- res/layout/my_layout.xml (with the "old" controls).
- res/layout-v15/my_layout.xml (with the "new" controls).

A device with API level 15 (i.e. ICS) or greater will use the "new" layout, while those with a lower API level will use the other one.

To simplify your code (e.g. usage of `findViewById()`) make sure that corresponding views in both layouts have the same ids.